# Zip CSV string containing GeoJSON to python dictionary

Tags: python, regex

I have a CSV string with a GeoJSON string in it.

```
str="""LC08,2016-08-02,"{'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[10,20],[50,40],[60,80],[15,45 ],[10,20]]]}",-9999,-9999"""
```

I intend to zip this string to a Python dict

I tried doing a regular split and zip function, but apparently the result isn't as expected. Because of the format of the string, the split is a hurdle.

This is what I have currently:

```
x="""LC08,2016-08-02,"{'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[10,20],[50,40],[60,80],[15,45 ],[10,20]]]}",-9999,-9999"""

values = x.split()
print(values)

row = dict( zip(('name', 'date', 'geometry', 'value0','value1'), values))
print(row)
```

I also tried to remove the quote characters using this:

```
values=re.sub('\r\n', '', re.sub(u'"', '', x))
values=values.split()
```

This hasn't really helped.

What I want to achieve is

```
{
 name:"LC08", 
 date:"2016-08-02", 
 geometry:"{'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[10,20],[50,40],[60,80],[15,45 ],[10,20]]]}",
 value0:"-9999",
 value1:"-9999"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you (probably) want is splitting with regular expressions, more precisely with the `regex` module:

```
import regex as re

string = """LC08,2016-08-02,"{'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[10,20],[50,40],[60,80],[15,45 ],[10,20]]]}",-9999,-9999"""

rx = re.compile(r"""\{[^{}]+\}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,""")

d = {}
d['name'], d['date'], d['geometry'], d['value0'], d['value1'] = rx.split(string)
print(d)
```

Which yields

```
{'name': 'LC08', 'date': '2016-08-02', 'geometry': '"{\'type\':\'Polygon\',\'coordinates\':[[[10,20],[50,40],[60,80],[15,45 ],[10,20]]]}"', 'value0': '-9999', 'value1': '-9999'}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/BjEQ0n/1) for the expression.

Comment: I'm running this on a Jupyter kernel and ```rx = re.compile(r"""\{[^{}]+\}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,""")``` says ```error: nothing to repeat```

Comment: @PranayNanda: Have you seen the `regex` module (`pip install regex`)? It does not work with the native `re` one.