# Read CSV and write to BigQuery from Apache Beam

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a GCS bucket from which I'm trying to read about 200k files and then write them to BigQuery. The problem is that I'm having trouble creating a PCollection that works well with the code. I'm following [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/blob/master/examples/dataflow-python-examples/dataflow_python_examples/data_ingestion.py#L100-L106) tutorial for reference.

I have this code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import logging
import os

from past.builtins import unicode

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText, ReadAllFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.metrics import Metrics
from apache_beam.metrics.metric import MetricsFilter
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from google.cloud import storage

import regex as re

# storage_client = storage.Client()
# bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('mybucket')
#
# blobs = bucket.list_blobs()
# l=list(blobs)
# x=[y.name for y in l]
# c=x[1:]
# print(len(c))
files = ['gs://mybucket/_chunk1',
         'gs://mybucket/_chunk0']


class DataIngestion:
    """A helper class which contains the logic to translate the file into
    a format BigQuery will accept."""

    def parse_method(self, string_input):

        x="""{}""".format(string_input)
        rx = re.compile(r"""\{[^{}]+\}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,""")
        d = {}
        d['name'], d['date'], d['geometry'], d['value0'], d['value1'], d['value2']=rx.split(x)
        d['geometry']=d['geometry'].strip('"')

        return d

def run(argv=None):
    """Main entry point; defines and runs the pipeline."""

    data_ingestion = DataIngestion()
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions())


    (p
    | 'Create PCollection' >> beam.Create(files)
    | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadAllFromText(skip_header_lines=1)
    | 'String To BigQuery Row' >> beam.Map(lambda s:
    data_ingestion.parse_method(s))
    | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(
    beam.io.BigQuerySink(
    'mytable',
    dataset='mydataset',
    schema=myschema,
    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)))

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  run()
```

The problem is that this code works perfect if `files` list has only one element. As soon as as there are more than 1 elements, the transform 'String To BigQuery Row' errors out and says `error: nothing to repeat [while running 'String To BigQuery Row']`. This probably is related to the regex module but I can't figure out what's wrong because it works perfectly when given 1 file.

Edit: Strangely it runs well via DirectRunner. I'm passing the `requirements.txt` file as given [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/).

This is how I'm executing the pipeline:

```
python streaming_inserts.py --runner=DataFlowRunner --project=my-project --temp_location=gs://temp/ --staging_location=gs://stage/  --requirements_file requirements.txt --disk_size_gb 1000 --region us-east1
```

My `requirements.txt` looks like this:

```
regex
google-cloud-storage
```

Also, as per logs, the package is being installed:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP's comment made me realize my mistake: the intended library is `regex`, not python's builtin `re`.

Using `import regex as re` was not only confusing to me, but is also causing the `re` library to throw the `nothing to repeat` error. This is because Dataflow does not by default save your main session.

When the code in your parsing function is being executed, it doesn't have access to the context of `re` you imported at build time. Normally, this would fail with a `NameError`, but because you're using a valid library name, the code assumes you mean the builtin `re` library and tries to execute it as such.

If you use `import regex` instead, you'll see `NameError: name 'regex' is not defined`, which is the real reason the code is failing. To get around this, either move the import statement into the parsing function itself, or pass `--save_main_session` as an option to the runner.
See [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors) for more details.

---

Old answer:

While I can't tell what version of Python you're using, it seems that your suspicion about the regex is correct. 
`*` is a special character indicating repeats of what came before it, but `(` is a special character that signifies a grouping, so a pattern like `(*SKIP)` doesn't seem grammatically correct.

In Python 3.7, the above expression doesn't even compile:

```
python -c 'import re; rx = re.compile(r"""\{[^{}]+\}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,""")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ajp1/miniconda3/envs/b-building/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 234, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/home/ajp1/miniconda3/envs/b-building/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/home/ajp1/miniconda3/envs/b-building/lib/python3.7/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/home/ajp1/miniconda3/envs/b-building/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 930, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/home/ajp1/miniconda3/envs/b-building/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/home/ajp1/miniconda3/envs/b-building/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 816, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
  File "/home/ajp1/miniconda3/envs/b-building/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/home/ajp1/miniconda3/envs/b-building/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 651, in _parse
    source.tell() - here + len(this))
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 11
```

Python 2.7.15 doesn't accept it either:

```
python2 -c 'import re; rx = re.compile(r"""\{[^{}]+\}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,""")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

While I don't know what strings you're trying to match, I suspect some of your characters need to be escaped. e.g. `"\{[^{}]+\}(\*SKIP)(\*FAIL)|,"`

Comment: Strange, I'm also using Python 2.7.15. And it works fine. This is the string I'm trying to match: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785481/zip-csv-string-containing-geojson-to-python-dictionary.

Comment: Also, adding the `*` gives `ValueError: too many values to unpack [while running 'String To BigQuery Row']`

Comment: Also, instead of doing `import re`, I'm doing `import regex as re` after doing `pip install regex`

Comment: Just noticed my confusion between `re` and `regex`, and have updated my answer accordingly. I recommend using `import regex` in the future instead to avoid the confusion